# How to prevent MDI windows being closed before app finished processing

Tags: delphi

I have an MDI application in which I have a MDI child doing some processing (needs 10-20 seconds to finish). I have discovered that if I close the main application, it crashes because the MDI child is closed to early (before finishing its processing).

The code is like this (it is way too complicated to put all code in here):

```
mainForm.OnButtonClick
begin
  start data processing;                         <--- 10 seconds
  create MDI child;                              <--- instant
     create visual controls (runtime)            <== 
        display the processed data in MDI child; <== 1 sec
end;
```

The program crashes on the 3rd line. FastMM says that "FastMM has detected an attempt to call a virtual method on a freed object". Obviously the MDI child has been freed.

How to prevent this?

Comment: Are you using Application.ProcessMessages (which should be named ProcessMessagesUnsafe and 'banned' for user-use - same as TThread.Suspend/Resume). If you think that calling ProcessMessages is safe, then think again, unless you get that ProcessMessages===unsafe/breaks GUI 'logic'/etc.

Comment: without ProcessMessages a single threaded app that does work cannot keep its UI responsive. But yes it does need some tricky reasoning to do this correctly.

Comment: +1 for David and +1 for kibab. You are both right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your MDI child window, do

```
procedure TForm2.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := not IsWorking;
end;
```

and do

```
mainForm.OnButtonClick
begin
  IsWorking := true;
  try
    start data processing;                         <--- 10 seconds
    create MDI child;                              <--- instant
       create visual controls (runtime)            <== 
          display the processed data in MDI child; <== 1 sec
  finally
    IsWorking := false;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: in FormCloseQuery you should note that the user has requested to close and then respond to this by closing when the work is finished. Ideally one would be able to cancel the work so that the close took place as soon as the user requested it to.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot read the OP's mind. This answers his question, that's all.

Comment: that was meant as an addition to your answer which I already upvoted and not meant as criticism. Also mind reading is an important skill here ;-)

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Voted as accepted. One question though: what about Windows shutdown? From what I remember, the CloseQuery signal is not sent to MDI childs when Window is shutting down. This means that the AV will still appear in this case (well, it is not critical as before).